# How to access element of class inside map C++

Tags: c++

I have a class named Client witch goes like this

```
class Client
 {
  public:
      Client(unsigned int id, std::string nom, std::string prenom, float solde);

      unsigned int getId() const;
      std::string getNom() const;
      std::string getPrenom() const;
      float getSolde() const;

      bool operator< (Client& client);
      friend std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& os, const Client& client);

      bool diminutionSolde(float diminution);

   private:
      unsigned int id_;
      std::string nom_;
      std::string prenom_;
      float solde_;
};
```

and i also have a class Article that goes like so

```
class Article
{
public:
     Article(unsigned int id, std::string nom, float prix);

     unsigned int getId() const;
     std::string getNom() const;
     float getPrix() const;

     bool operator< (Article& article);
     friend std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& os, const Article& article);

private:
     unsigned int id_;
     std::string nom_;
     float prix_;
};
```

I also have another class (which I don't think is necessary to show) that as map as an attribut,

```
   std::map<Client , BasketArticles* > mapClientPanier_;
```

which BasketArticles as a list < T >  as attribut;

first of all, do I need to use a pointer on the client ?

Then, how do i access the clients articles, one by one to stream them on the screen, like std::cout <<

and/or pout the name of the client and the Articles he have in a new map (which will be in alphabetical order) and then std::cout << all that.

Answer (score 0):

Whether or not you need a pointer depends entirely on how your `BasketArticles` class instances are constructed: what's responsible for instantiating and destroying them. If your `BasketArticles` instance are instantiated elsewhere, and you would like the map to reference them, obviously you need a pointer. Otherwise, if the instances of `BasketArticles` should only exists in the map, then it's better to avoid using pointers, and have `std::map` responsible for instantiating them.

Comment: -> and would you help me with the accesing problem, this is major for me as i need to do it in several other method().

Comment: Your question "how do i access the clients articles" does not mean anything. You have a std::map. Accessing the contents of your std::map is no different than accessing the contents of any other std::map. Use iterators, begin(), end(); or find(); or any other of the usual std::map methods.\